# What things Intel HD graphics controls in addition to gaming

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, gpu, intel-graphics, nvidia

I set Intel HD Graphics settings from performance to quality for improved quality during gaming.

I want to know will these settings affect any other applications...or what exactly are the applications/settings integrated GPU controls ?

CPU - Intel Pentium 2127U IVY BRIDGE

[image]

Comment: You will have to be more specific about which features you have enabled.  Intel has added and removed features in past releases of their driver.  Please [edit] your question to include this vital information.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know will these settings affect any other applications...or what exactly are the applications/settings integrated GPU controls ?

According to Intel:

> Application Optimal Mode enables some application specific
> optimizations. This is similar in concept to the per-game
> profiles/optimizations applied by AMD or NVidia. Normally you should
> leave this enabled for best game performance and to allow driver to
> work around some game bugs.

Additionally, based on your current settings a given application's Anisotropic Filtering or Vertical Sync configuration will be respected, instead of overriding the behavior on specific applications.

Source: [What exactly does Application Optimal Mode do and...](https://community.intel.com/t5/Graphics/What-exactly-does-Application-Optimal-Mode-do-and/td-p/366163#:%7E:text=Application%20Optimal%20Mode%20enables%20some,work%20around%20some%20game%20bugs.)

If you want to know the different between Quality and Performance the tool tips for each provide an adequate description.

> You can also click the "ToolTips" ( ? circled in red) to get additional information about each setting.